# Is it possible to set borders to grid view in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to set borders to grid view in xml. Like, i want each grid cell to contain borders. If so, kindly let me know how to do it. I have set this way. But i am not finding any specific thing to set border.

```
    <GridView
       android:layout_marginTop="95px" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="32px"
       android:id="@+id/gridview"  
       android:layout_width="340px"   
       android:layout_height="250px"  
       android:columnWidth="35px"             
       android:numColumns="7" 
       android:scrollbars="none"
       android:verticalSpacing="14px"   
       android:horizontalSpacing="18px"  
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="@color/white">
</GridView>
```

Thank you
Swathi